# If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^n} = \frac{1}{m}$, is there an efficient way to calculate $m$ from $k$ if both are natural?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, algorithms

I have this formula, where $k$ and $m$ are natural numbers:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^n} = \frac{1}{m}
$$

In what efficient way do we be able to calculate $m$ by given $k$ with knowledge that they are natural? Is there an algorithm to find $m$ by $k$?

Comment: I expect you are familiar with [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)?

Comment: @EricTowers No. Is geometric series can help to find this algorithm?

Comment: You are misusing the term *algorithm*, which denotes an automatic procedure to perform a computation. What you are after is a *closed-form* expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your series is a geometric series (only missing the term for $n=0$ which is equal to 1) that converges for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ that satisfy $k>1$.

Then the series is equal to $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{k}}-1=\frac{1}{k-1}$.
Thus $m=k-1$.

(You might want to take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum)

Does that answer your question?